# Integral with modified bessel function and exponentials

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the following equations

$\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(-\frac{\alpha}{x+1}\right)\exp(-c x) x^{\frac{n-1}{2}} I_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{\beta x}\right)\ \mathrm{d}x $

and

$\int^\infty_0 \exp\left(-\frac{\alpha}{x}\right)\exp(-cx)(x-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}} I_{n-1}\left(\sqrt{\beta(x-1)}\right) \mathrm{d}x $

I tried using Mellin convolution, but I always struggle with the inversion part. Any other hints or clues are welcomed.

Comment: The solution to the question given here may help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278484/integral-involving-laguerre-gaussian-and-modified-bessel-function